# No javac compiler error but mouseEntered method is not working

Tags: java, swing, hover, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am trying to make a program where when you hover over an element, it will be set as non-visible and a new one will be set visible in a different place. However when I hover over the button, nothing happens. There is no compiler error to tell me what to fix so I came to stack overflow. I am very inexperienced in Java and I just started yesterday so if you could please dumb it down for me. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class hover {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Java Swing UI");
        GridLayout l = new GridLayout(2,4);
        JButton b = new JButton("Click me!");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Click me!");
        f.setSize(500,300);
        f.setLayout(l);
        b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        b2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.add(b);
        f.add(b2);
        b2.setVisible(false);

        b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { 

                if (e.getSource() == f) {
                    b.setVisible(false);
                    b2.setVisible(true);
                }


            }

        });
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am very inexperienced in Java and I just started yesterday

So the first thing you need to learn is how to do some basic debugging by using System.out.println(…) to see if you logic does what you expect it to do. For example:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { 
    System.out.println("mouse entered");
    if (e.getSource() == f) {
        System.out.println("if statement");
        b.setVisible(false);
        b2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you did then you would notice that you would NOT see "if statement" displayed when you run your code. So the question is why?

```
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

You added the MouseListener to the "b" variable.

```
if (e.getSource() == f) {
```

But your if statement checks if the event came from the "f" variable, which will never be true.

There is no need for the if statement, since the event can only be generated for the "b" button. Therefore you just need:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{ 
        b.setVisible(false);
        b2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! I have used this technique in many other programming languages, guess I just didn't think of it! I can't actually upvote your post because I dont have fifteen karma, but thanks!